# Vertex degrees in minimally biconnected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Suppose that $G$ is minimally biconnected (in terms of vertices). Show that $\exists \{v_1,...,v_m\}$, $m\geq4$ such that degree($v_i$) = 2 $\forall 1 \leq i \leq m$ (of course, $|V(G)| \geq 4$).

Due to $G$ being minimally biconnected, there must be an open ear decomposition...but how do I go on from there?

Comment: Could you please explain what "minimally biconnected (in terms of vertices)" means?

Comment: $G$ is biconnected, but $G-x$ is not $\forall x \in V(G)$.